# What is the shortcut for invert color on Mac OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macos

I did some search but find the most discussed shortcut  <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>8</kbd> is not working anymore. Is it changed or do I need to set it manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Apple Menu -> System Preferences. Click on Keyboard and then click the tab Keyboard shortcuts.
Then scroll select the Acessability option in the left pane and scroll down and check the box beside Invert color.

Comment: great except this is NOT a shortcut.  The answer to the question would be to go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > check "invert colors", now your Command-Option-Control-8 will work.

Answer (score -3):

Try hitting: <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd>.

That's how I get it.